# pygame, getting a sprite to move to cursor position on click

Tags: pygame

I was trying to make a tower defense sort of game in pygame. When I click on the screen, I want it to be able to move the tower sprite to the position. Currently, when I run the program, it moves the sprite to the cursor with out clicking, then does not let me move it again.

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()

WINDOWWIDTH = 1800
WINDOWHEIGHT = 1800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
background_colour = (188,69,80)

GAMETITLE = "Tower Defence"

def main():


pygame.display.set_caption(GAMETITLE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

spritegroup =pygame.sprite.Group()
sprite =pygame.sprite.Sprite()
tower =  sprite.image = pygame.image.load("tower.png")
sprite.image = tower
sprite.rect = sprite.image.get_rect()

sprite.rect.x = 10
sprite.rect.y = 10

sprite.add(spritegroup)
while True:


    screen.fill(background_colour)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), ((0, 100), (1100, 90)))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255,255), ((1010, 100), (100, 600)))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), ((1010, 700), (2400, 90)))
    spritegroup.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed():

        cursorPos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        sprite.rect.x = cursorPos[0]
        sprite.rect.y = cursorPos[1]
```

main()

Comment: Make sure to format your code correctly. Also, it seems you're new to pygame. You'll need to create an event loop and process events regularly so the event queue doesn't fill up. And `pygame.sprite.Sprite` is meant as a base class to define your own objects by inheriting. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pygame/5110/event-handling/18046/event-loop#t=201702041751283263283) how the event loop functions and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pygame/3959/getting-started-with-pygame/14697/a-simple-game#t=201702041751256893131) is a simple walkthrough of pygame.

Comment: `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` returns a tuple of length three. You probably want `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]` which will check if the left mouse button is  pressed. [Here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) is the documentation.

Comment: I just tried out your game. If you fix the issues I've commented about above, it'll work.

Comment: BTW: you can set directly `sprite.rect.topleft = pygame.mouse.get_pos()` or center `sprite.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()`

Answer (score 0):

what is happening is that `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` returns a tuple. if statements return true if they are not null. this means that regardless if it is pressed it will return True. then the pygame event queue will fill with mouse events and never get processed. your event loop should look something like:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.event.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        #stuff to do on click
```